# Is there a way to include CSS isolation using Angular 1.5.9

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

**Is there a way to include CSS isolation using Angular 1.5.9?**

The company I work for is stuck using Angular 1.5.9 for a while and I am wanting to include some newer component techniques to our workflow.

One thing I have been wanting to do is CSS isolation.

I have been reading up on how Angular 2 does this but as it dynamically generates html attributes and applies them to the CSS selector which is great but hard to replicate. I have had no luck finding a way to include this techniques to AngularJS.

So is there a way to do CSS isolation using AngularJS?

Comment: This question does not appear to be a duplicate. It's similar, but not the same. The original question and its accepted answer even predates Angular  as well as Angular 1.5.

Comment: Mike it's cool I think it points me in the right direction. You can see with the info you gave where it got me. I placed an answer to that question just to put a different option out there for other people. I gave you the points as it was the closest to get me to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with this a bit and putting component specific CSS within a `<style>` tag in templates seems like the best way to go.

I've tried to get ng-bind-html, ng-src and a few other things to work here to load the css from an external file, but didn't have any success.

Comment: Thinking about using inline styles you could take a method from React and place the styles in a controller or a service and use ng-style to link it into the template